# Canot resolve dependency via NuGet

Tags: .net, msbuild, nuget

I have a C#-project that is using a 3rd-party dependency as well as some of my own assemblies.

All of those assemblies are located within my `CommonBinPath` in `C:\repo\bin`.

Now for the sake of gaining experience using NuGet also I plan to consume some of those dependencies - essentially all assemblies from third parties - via out NuGet-server.

So I have the following references within my project-file:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <CommonBinPath Condition="'$(CommonBinPath)' == ''">$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\bin\Debug</CommonBinPath>
    <OutputPath>$(CommonBinPath)\</OutputPath>
</PropertyGroup> 
<ItemGroup>
  <PackageReference Include="ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase">
    <Version>*</Version>
  </PackageReference>
  <Reference Include="GeoDataServer">
    <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion
    <HintPath>$(CommonBinPath)\GeoDataServer.dll</HintPath>
  </Reference>
</ItemGroup>
```

So the ArcGIS-assembly can be found under `CommonBinPath` as well as on our server. However when I compile that project neither can be found and I get namespace not found errors.

From my msbuild-log:

```
ResolveAssemblyReference-target
  Dependency "ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase, Version=10.6.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=8fc3cc631e44ad86".
      The resolved path is "C:\repo\bin\ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase.dll".
      A reference was found in path "C:\repo\bin".
          For SearchPath "C:\repo\bin".
          Considered "C:\repo\bin\ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase.winmd", but it didn't exist.
      Required by "GeoDataServer".
```

This is just the translated version from my german log-file, I hope I got the correct keywords.

So obviously during the `ResolveAssemblyReference`-target the reference is found within my local file-system. So far so good.

However during `Csc` I get this:

```
Target "CoreCompile" in File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Roslyn\Microsoft.CSharp.Core.targets" from project "C:\MyProject.csproj" (Target "Compile" depends on it):
The target "CoreCompile" will be created.
The output-file "obj\x86\Debug\MyProject.dll" does not exist
The Csc-target from C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Roslyn\Microsoft.Build.Tasks.CodeAnalysis.dll will be used.
Csc-target
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Roslyn\csc.exe /noconfig /unsafe- /checked- /nowarn:1701,1702 /nostdlib+ /platform:x86 /errorreport:prompt /warn:4 /baseaddress:285212672 /define:FI60 /highentropyva+ /reference:C:\repo\bin\GeoDataServer.dll /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5.1\mscorlib.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5.1\System.Core.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5.1\System.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5.1\System.Xml.dll" /debug+ /debug:full /filealign:4096 /optimize- /out:obj\x86\Debug\MyProject.dll /ruleset:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\Team Tools\Static Analysis Tools\\Rule Sets\MinimumRecommendedRules.ruleset" /subsystemversion:6.00 /target:library /warnaserror- /utf8output GeometryAssert.cs Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs "C:\Users\utvm-admin\AppData\Local\Temp\.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.1.AssemblyAttributes.cs"
  ...
GeometryAssert.cs(9,7): error CS0246: The type or namespace "ESRI" could not be found (maybe you are missing a using-directive). [C:\MyProject.csproj]
```

I´m doing this on our jenkins-server where no VS is installed, but the VS Build Tools 2019. However on my own machine where I have a "full" VS2017 installed everfthing works fine (of course I have the appropriate `using` within my file).

EDIT: I realized the `ResolveNuGetPackageAssets`-target, that is executed directly before `ResolveAssemblyReference`, was omitted, "because the condition was false":

```
('$(ResolveNuGetPackages)' == 'true' and exists('$(ProjectLockFile)')) evaluated to ('true' == 'true' and exists('obj\project.assets.json'))
```

However I would expect the dependencies to be resolved by `ResolveAssemblyReference` if they were not already resolved during `ResolveNuGetPackageAssets`. Is this wrong? How do those two targets relate?